# How to create app shortcut for non activity class

Tags: java, android

I create an app shortcut for nonactivity class. nonactivity class makes the custome dialog view on the main Activity. but I clicked the shortcut icon it says the app isn't installed.How to fixed it. Help me, please.

I tried but didn't find the solution.

```java
    public void createShortcut(){
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
            ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);


            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassA.class);
            intent_bal.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            ShortcutInfo shortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this,"shortcut1")
                    .setShortLabel("test1")
                    .setLongLabel("tessssst1")
                    .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_shortcut))
                    .setIntent(intent)
                    .build();

            shortcutManager.addDynamicShortcut(Collections.singletonList(shortcutInfo));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your manifest.xml file?

Comment: Manifest has a shortcut permission code but no code related to ClassA. I know activity shortcut needs to add some intent filter code in manifest but ClassA is the non-activity class, therefore, no code related the ClassA in manifest now.